# Sentiment Analysis on Twitter Data?

Tags: twitter, dataset, sentiment-analysis

I am working on this project where I wish to classify the general mood of a Twitter user from his recent tweets. Since the tweets can belong to a huge variety of domains how should I go about it ?

I could use the Naive Bayes algorithm (like here: http://phpir.com/bayesian-opinion-mining) but since the tweets can belong to a large variety of domains, I am not sure if this will be very accurate.

The other option is using maybe sentiment dictionaries like [SentiWordNet](http://sentiwordnet.isti.cnr.it/) or [here](http://alexdavies.net/2011/10/word-lists-for-sentiment-analysis-of-twitter/). Would this be a better approach, I don't know.

Also where can I get data to train my classifier if I plan to use the Naive Bayes or some other algorithm ?

Just to add here, I am primarily coding in PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you could use `SentiWordNet` as the *classifier* data if you are focused on a word-by-word approach.  It is how simple `Bayesian spam filters` works; it focuses on each word.

The advantage here is that while many of the words in `SentiWordNet` have multiple meanings, each with different `positive/objective/negative` scores, you could experiment with using the scores of the other words in the tweet to narrow in on the most appropriate meaning for each multi-meaning word, which could give you a more accurate score for each word and for the overall tweet.